# Excel Find if value is within interval and return interval category

Tags: excel, vba, formulas

I have a lot of numbers in column A.
In column B I want to be able to retrieve the right category found in column D based on the interval specified in column E-F.
VBA or formula would help a lot!

You can see the end result with a few ranges and values in the attatched picture.

[End result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEBjQ.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated a simple INDEX/MATCH will do it:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(A2,E:E))
```

Comment: Just on a side note: the [Match()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) function allows for more options. Yet, Scott chose to omit the last parameter which ensures that the `match_type` defaults to `1`. Thus match finds *MATCH finds the largest value that is less than or equal to lookup_value*. But for this to work your table must be always *in ascending* (as it is right now). So, make sure that you keep it that way.